# iOS 13 UITabBarItem Offset Issue

Tags: ios, xcode, ios13, xcode11

It seems that on iOS 13 / XCode 11, when you want a tab bar item that is centered with no text, you simply don't provide a title. This is what you would expect, but in previous versions of xcode this wasn't the case, the usual solution was to set an offset on the tab bar item. The problem now is I can't find a way to appease both iOS 13 devices and older devices without doing something programmatic (I'm using storyboards), which I can't believe Apple would have such a large oversight.

Does anyone know what the proper solution is to this without putting in a programmatic system version check?